# Change box width in smartdiagram flow chart in LaTeX

Tags: latex, flowchart

I would like to change the box width in smartdiagramset so that the each sentence stays on a single line. Here is my code for the flow chart

```
\begin{figure} \centering \smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true}

\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{\fontsize{5pt}{12pt}\selectfont{EPS:\\ 193 tests\\ 745 compounds\\ 15 Species\\  Weeds \& crops \\ Toxicity ignored},   \fontsize{6pt}{12pt}\selectfont{PPS: \\ Weeds \& Crops \\ }, \fontsize{6pt}{12pt}\selectfont{SPS:}, \fontsize{6pt}{12pt}\selectfont{Field trials}}   \caption{Flow chart of herbicidal selection process} \end{figure}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 1):

The width of the text is `1.75cm` per default, you can increase it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true,text width=2cm, font=\fontsize{6pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{% 
    EPS:\\ 
    193 tests\\ 
    745 compounds\\ 
    15 Species\\  
    Weeds \& crops\\ 
    Toxicity ignored,
    PPS: \\ Weeds \& Crops, 
    SPS:,
    Field trials
}  

\end{document}
```

[image]